# Lost all linux azure VM changes from 8/16 - 8/22. Possible to get those changes back & What can I do in the future to avoid this?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I'm having a serious concern with my azure VM, as the title says I lost all of my change from 8/16 to 8/22. This was noticed on the 23rd, I am wondering if due to maintenance all changes were reverted back to 8/16? I need to know if its possible to get the VM back to state it was at the end of the day 8/22.

More importantly - I need to know how to avoid such regressions of the VM in the future.

Comment: If this is indeed related to the outage, as suggested by @stackpointcloud, then this question should be closed, as it has nothing to do with programming; it would be specifically an Azure service support issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible you were affected by the recent Azure outage:

http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2014/08/how-microsofts-azure-outage-will-affect-its-slas/

You will need to contact MSFT on this one. For the future, I would recommend setting up a periodic snapshot process for each VM so you have a running backup.

-matt

Comment: Just wondering how this qualifies as an accepted answer. It just points to the outage report. Then again, the question should be closed if it is, indeed, related to the outage and not some other configuration-related issue.

Comment: @DavidMakogon You bring up a good point - perhaps I should not have accepted it because the root cause is still unclear. I just opened up a support ticket with the idea that there could be a possible relationship between the outage and my issue but that is by no means definite.